# Error while building xgboost.sln

Tags: python, git, visual-studio, xgboost

I cloned xgboost with package through git
xgboost is with GPU support

I am getting errors when building xgboost.sln

```
error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Release\gpuxgboost.lib'
```

I'm using VS 2017.
Any help appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you add path to `gpuxgboost.lib` to VS project settings?

Comment: How do you put that?